# What is better for rendering in cycles? A network? Or a single monster workstation?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, gpu, performance, network

Is it better to have multiple render nodes and do rendering over the network? 
If so - is there a special software to set this up and is it hard to configure this? Is there a max amount of render nodes?

Or would it be better to have one "monster" workstation with multiple GPUs (5-6 GPUs)?

As far as i know Maya only supports 4 render-nodes... so my question is if there is such a limit in Blender? And the other question if it is difficult to set up a render-farm or render-nodes: I have never tried it so my question is if i will run in a lot of problems if i will try it (i want to use a GPU-based renderer like Cycles). I hope i have explained my thoughts now enough. Thanks for kindness with a noob :-)

---

As far as i know Maya only supports 4 render-nodes... so my question is if there is such a limit in Blender? And the other question if it is difficult to set up a render-farm or render-nodes: I have never tried it so my question is if i will run in a lot of problems if i will try it (i want to use a GPU-based renderer like Cycles). I hope i have explained my thoughts now enough. Thanks for kindness with a noob :-)

Comment: Could you please clarify? This is very unclear, I have no idea what exactly you are asking

Comment: @NoviceInDisguise As far as I can see, they're asking about whether it is more efficient to set up network rendering or have a single super powerful workstation.

Comment: yes, this is exactly what i want to know :-)

Comment: I've never used an extensive and proper network system (or a monster workstation).. I would imagine the network causes some overhead, but would be more easily scaled up at a later time. These are just wild speculations though.

Comment: I guess it all depends on what kind of scenes you'll be rendering. The upside of GPUs is that they sometimes they do render faster when working on cycles. The downside is that the memory usage for GPUs is quite limited, so there will be times when you'll have to render on CPU no matter what. A test would yield more information on your question: do a sample render of your project on a render farm service. You'll be able to assess what works best for your needs before you spend a lot of cash.

Answer (score 4):

That will depend on the task and the level of effort you want to put into it.

If you are rendering an animation then you will easily benefit from using multiple machines, each machine can render a single frame at the same time giving a very linear speedup based on number of machines. There is a network render addon included with blender. You may want to look at [Flamenco](http://www.flamenco.io/) which is the new render farm being developed for the [gooseberry project](http://gooseberry.blender.org/). You could also manually start each machine with a different range of frames. There are also a few render farms available that you can pay by the hour or some similar metric.

If you are rendering a single image then a single machine is the easy way to go. There is no freely available way to break up a single image to render it on multiple machines, it can be done but currently you will need to break up the image and combine it yourself or create an automated way to do it.

There are no restrictions to number of machines you can use on any of the render farm options.

Answer (score 0):

I have had good luck with the Brenda project as a starting point to render inexpensively on AWS - https://github.com/jamesyonan/brenda

This allows rendering in many different ways.  E.g. multiple frames per node, splitting up frames across nodes, and much more.

You can also use AWS spot pricing so it can be extremely inexpensive.  Works great for me when I'm in a hurry to get something done.